# Add integer to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to add an integer to an array but I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

for i in range(1, 621):
    with h5py.File("C:\\A" + str(i) + ".out") as f:
        data = np.array(f['rxs']['rx1']['Ey'])
        data.append(0)
    np.savetxt("C:\\A" + str(i) + ".csv", data, delimiter = ",")
```

For this I keep getting an error saying: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'"

I have also tried concatenate with an array consisting just 1 integer but it doesn't work. I used these lines for that:

```
data = np.array(f['rxs']['rx1']['Ey'])
b = np.array([[0]])
np.concatenate(data, b)
```

I get this error for this one: "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

The original aim of my code is to convert HDF files to CSV files which works if I don't try to change the array.

Could you please help?

Comment: try using `np.append(a,0)`

Comment: Be aware that `np.append` is inefficient as it always creates and returns a modified copy of the array. The original array isn't modified.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Unless you store the result in the same array name

Comment: @Bazingaa But even then first a new array has to be allocated, data of previous array copied and finally the previous array deleted. For a Python `list.append` this happens only sometimes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: So what are the situations when `np.append` should be used and when should it be avoided?

Comment: @Bazingaa If you have a large number of items (unfortunately I can't give a more precise number) which should be appended at once, `np.append` is better. Where the data only arrives item by item, a `list` as buffer can be useful where the items are collected until the list is large enough to append it to a numpy array.

Comment: You can just use `data=np.append(f['rxs']['rx1']['Ey'], 0)` . Or if it's a list, attempt `np.array(f['rxs']['rx1']['Ey'] + [0])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not dealing with a python `list` but a `numpy array`.

To solve the problem at hand you can use [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

```
data = np.append(data, 0)
```

You can also not create a numpy array to begin with. What is the type of `f['rxs']['rx1']['Ey']`? (You can find out with `print(type(f['rxs']['rx1']['Ey']))`)

if it is a list, you can simply do

```
data = f['rxs']['rx1']['Ey']
data.append(0)
```

Comment: Updated the answer with another suggestion. Accept the answer if it resolves your issue so other people do not look at the question

Comment: It says "<class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>". But your answer solved my problem. Thanks!